# Identity Server 4 Discovery Endpoint showing Http links instead of Https, eventhough accessed from Https

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, identityserver4, amazon-elb

I have a .net core 3.1 web application with Identity server 4, which runs with reverse proxy Nginx. and a load balancer infront with https. When accessed locally discovery end point shows https but when deployed end points shows http instead of https when accessed with https endpoint with valid certificate and proper dns.

tried adding x-forward headers also in both code and also in nginx config.

Comment: How did you set up the identity server? Post relevant sections of `Startup.cs` and `appsettings.json` if it's configured from there.

Comment: Also, where have you deployed the code?

Answer (score 0):

In our Identityserver host implementation we use the following middleware:

```cs
 app.Use((context, next) =>
 {
    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SSL_OFFLOAD") == "true")
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
 });
```

Close to the top of the

```cs
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

Where `SSL_OFFLOAD` is just a custom environment variable, introduced in the `docker service create`.
Works fine for years.